# Team chat for Mac OS/Ubuntu (with voice, history and bots etc.)

Tags: xmpp, chat, skype, voice, collaboration

We are small webdev team (currently 7 up to 15 members in future).

We going to make startups and need group text chat with voice option, logs option (new user can view history as in skype group chat) and bots.

Currently we use Skype group chats (good for group text and voice chat, also allow history viewing). But I don't know how to create Skype bots (I mean information bots - about Mercurial Bitbucket commits, about new team forum messages, new emails to support@ mailbox, new issues on our Kanban task board etc.)

So my question is how to create Skype bots or may be we should switch to (for example) Jabber (please provide more info about server, can we use GoogleTalk for that or need to install another server, and about client (best for Mac OS and Ubuntu)).

I know about http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software but not sure what do we need to choose. Ideally install only clients (like Skype) and save time on server part administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Skype bot maybe this answers your need:

https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot

Disclaimer: I am 50% of the authors, so I can answer more detailed questions if you add them in the comments. However, HTTP + scripting interface should provide almost anything you can imagine out of the box.

Comment: The bot was in fact created for the needs of a small web dev team.